# How to change labels in a pickle dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pickle

I have a pickle dataset with images and corresponding labels. Some of the labels are wrong and I would like to correct them.

How can I do it? I need to inspect the images first.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you maybe list what you have tried to do as well?

Comment: Not much. I have no idea how to start. I couldn't find anything useful in Google.